# botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7.3 and trying to run [chalice](https://github.com/awslabs/chalice)

However, when I run

> chalice deploy

I get back:

> botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/helloworld"

I can't find any information on what's causing this. My AWS configuration was setup and tested to be working with boto.

My config:

`[default]
output = table
region = us-west-1`

Comment: Can you paste your ~/.aws/config without the credentials?

Comment: `[default]
output = table
region = us-west-1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your config you have setup the region to `region = us-west-1` and you are trying to access a Lambda function in region us-east-1.

Change that region to us-east-1 in the config and then give it a try it will work.

Comment: im getting OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory which seems like a chalice related error

Comment: See this https://github.com/awslabs/chalice/issues/33 error that is a known Chalise error of virtual environment try reporting that on that thread.