# AWS Connection error to Endpoint URL for Rekognition

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I have just started with AWS Rekognition and I have run into a problem that I can't seem to solve.

I am using the Python script supplied on [Detecting Text in an Image - Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/text-detecting-text-procedure.html) to test how the service works and how I could possibly integrate it into other apps.

I know that I have entered the correct data for the config and credential files, found here:

```
~/.aws/credentials
```

as other services such as S3 work without a problem using command line code. In the supplied code (I will include it at the end) I have specified the correct bucket as well as the name of the picture I'm trying to use.
When running the script, on terminal everything works fine until after a few seconds the following error message is displayed:

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint 
 URL: "https://rekognition.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/"
```

I have also tried several other availability zones such as:

```
us-east-1, us-west-1, eu-central-1
```

yet they all result in the same error.

A similar issue has already been discussed in [python - botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533897/botocore-exceptions-endpointconnectionerror-could-not-connect-to-the-endpoint). However, the solution offered in that discussion did not solve the problem I am encountering. I would appreciate any help and tips that can solve this issue.

```
import boto3

bucket='bucket'
photo='inputtext.jpg'

client=boto3.client('rekognition')

response=client.detect_text(Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket':bucket,'Name':photo}})

textDetections=response['TextDetections']
print response
print 'Matching faces'
for text in textDetections:
        print 'Detected text:' + text['DetectedText']
        print 'Confidence: ' + "{:.2f}".format(text['Confidence']) + "%"
        print 'Id: {}'.format(text['Id'])
        if 'ParentId' in text:
            print 'Parent Id: {}'.format(text['ParentId'])
        print 'Type:' + text['Type']
        print
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code worked perfectly fine for me.

I connected to the Sydney region:

```
client=boto3.client('rekognition',region_name='ap-southeast-2')
```

Please note that the [supported regions for Amazon Rekognition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#rekognition_region) are (as of writing this answer):

- us-east-2
- us-east-1
- us-west-2
- ap-southeast-2
- ap-northeast-1
- eu-west-1

Comment: Hello, I changed to the region of eu-west-1, I am now receiving another error. It has to do with the script though. The error I receive is:                                                         File "text1.py", line 11
    print response
                 ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(response)?

Comment: Python 3 requires print(xx). Python 2 does not.